# How can I setup an RSS type notification service?

Tags: cordova, notifications, data-synchronization

Background: I have a PhoneGap application set up on iOS and Android with plugins that allow me to queue system/local notifications when the app is in the background. I know that it won't work if the app was quit or killed, or if it hasn't been started since install/power on, but these are not too important.

What I want to do is create a database that will hold notifications (associated with an app name), and have the app periodically (5 minutes?) do a getJSON request (jQuery) to the server and retrieve any notifications.

What I want to know is - how can I make the device know which notifications it should pull from the server, without ever duplicating one? Do I need to store the id of every notification the device has ever retrieved to ensure it doesn't get duplicates? This seems like it would store a lot of unnecessary data on the device and could get messed up if local data is cleared. I guess this would function like an RSS in that it would get the most recent info, but not duplicate.